# Verbose output of git svn

Tags: git, svn, version-control

Can someone tell me - is where are way to get verbose output from git svn fetch?

If i try to run:

```
git svn fetch --verbose / git svn fetch --v
```

I receive:

```
Unknown option: verbose/ Unknown option: v
```

Cant find anything about this problem on the web, git svn version:

```
git-svn version 2.6.4 (svn 1.9.4)
```

My task is to find out is where are any new commits i get from fetch.
With git fetch -v - i can check is where are new commits, can i do same thing with svn?

Or maybe i can use some other git svn command to understand is where are any new commits on remote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git svn fetch` is not support `--verbose` option. It seems you wan to find where the remote is located.

You can find the remote svn location (URL) in `.git/svn/.metadata` or `.git/config` file.

Comment: Hi! I want to find out is where are new commits on remote.
With git i use "git fetch --verbose" and when check output - if where are string like "b796438..6335e69 branch_name -> branch name" when remote has a new commits. If all strings are like "= [up to date] branch_name -> branch name" - where are no new commits. Is where are a way to do similar with git svn?

Comment: No, `git svn fetch` will download and apply new version from svn directly. So you can detect if `git svn fetch` has output, if there is no output, that means no new version in svn.

Comment: Yes, this is totaly i wanted! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -3):

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn

When you say you couldn't find anything on the web, I'm a bit surprised because this took about two seconds :)

It does add the caveat that there is imperfect compatibility, so perhaps the specific combination you were attempting is one of the things impacted by that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIPPx.jpg)

Comment: It is argument for git svn log not fetch. https://yadi.sk/i/d2RCkdhE3HRFpe